# Error while fetching SAML token by using an OBO request with shared secret with AzureAD

Tags: azure-active-directory, postman, saml-2.0

While performing a test using Postman to fetch SAML token by using an OBO request against AzureAD I am getting the below error :

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "AADSTS50013: Assertion failed signature validation. [Reason - The key was not found., Thumbprint of key used by client: 'xxxxxxxxxx']\r\nTrace ID: 52c2d92d-1c86-4695-9eb9-a5a71aa94000\r\nCorrelation ID: 263c4f69-4e29-4042-b4f3-3edc6c6ed5d2\r\nTimestamp: 2021-05-17 18:17:12Z",
    "error_codes": [
        50013
    ],
    "timestamp": "2021-05-17 18:17:12Z",
    "trace_id": "52c2d92d-1c86-4695-9eb9-a5a71aa94000",
    "correlation_id": "263c4f69-4e29-4042-b4f3-3edc6c6ed5d2",
    "error_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=50013"
}
```

Here goes the Postman request details :

[image]

Can anyone help me here by providing their guidance to fix this issue?

Comment: Hi, please see this [blog](https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2019/08/understanding-azure-ads-on-behalf-of-flow-aka-obo-flow/), *"Root cause: Web API 1 is a SAML Application (check the Enterprise Application blade to see if Single sign-on is enabled and there is a SAML signing Certificate attached)."*

Comment: Thanks @PamelaPeng for your response. I already referred to that article and can confirm that Web API 1 is a SAML application and  Single Sign-on is enabled and there is a SAML signing Certificate attached to it.

Comment: arent you missing the resource parameter...  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow#obtain-a-saml-token-by-using-an-obo-request-with-a-shared-secret

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the above issue after proper verification of the Bearertoken from the request details. The solution works fine in case of complete OIDC apps flow